# R: How to use monospaced (fixed width) font in grid.table?

Tags: r, gridextra, monospace

I want to display my grid.table in monospaced (fixed width) fonts.

How shall I specify this? Is it any particular fonts to be used, or any other arguments?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grid.table(head(iris), theme=ttheme_default(base_family="monospace"))
```

[image: iris]

This will use your system monospace font, which, in my case, is [Cousine](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cousine).  Feel free to change it as you wish.